# What would be the equivalent of this code using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
int main() {
    std::deque<My_Int*> table;

    My_Int* table_entry = new My_Int(2);
    table.push_back (table_entry);

    My_Int** new_obj = &table.front();

    *new_obj = new My_Int(3); 
    
    std::cout << table.front()->data << std::endl; // prints 3 as intended
}
```

I'm mainly confused about the line with the double pointer. How would I replicate this using smart pointers? Thanks for any help. (I know the code doesn't do proper clean up)

EDIT: Just for clarification, the deque when using smart pointers would be a deque of shared_pointers as well.

Comment: Would you know how to change it to a `std::shared_ptr` if the code would use the simpler `My_Int*& new_obj = table.front();`?

Comment: Unrelated: Remember that in C++you do not have to `new` objects. You may be able to avoid a level of indirection with `std::deque<My_Int> table;` and then `table.emplace_back (2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<My_Int>> table;

    table.push_back (std::make_shared<My_Int>(2));

    std::shared_ptr<My_Int> &new_obj = table.front();

    new_obj = std::make_shared<My_Int>(3);

    std::cout << table.front()->data << std::endl;
}
```

This is the solution i've come up with from yyyy's answer. I've never seen the & operator be used when declaring a shared_ptr, but I suppose it makes sense.

If anyone could shed light on how the & operator works in this context, it still is a bit confusing to me. Thanks

Comment: It's not an operator in this context, it declares a variable of reference (to a `std::shared_ptr<My_Int>`) type

Comment: FWIW You could have also declared it as `std::shared_ptr<My_Int>* new_obj = &table.front();` (and used `*new_obj = ` in the next line) but it's less common to do so in C++

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, but then that wouldn't be a shared pointer

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It would be a pointer to a shared pointer, which is extremely similar to the reference to a shared pointer you have in this answer